# How to redefine the section counter in amsart?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I'm using the document class `amsart`, which defines the `section` counter as follows:

```
\newcounter{section}
```

However, I want the `section` counter to reset to zero every time I start a new `part`. Thus, I put in the preamble of my document the following code:

```
\newcounter{section}[part]
```

However, since the `section` counter was already defined in `amsart`, I'm receiving the error message:

```
Command \c@section already defined.
```

What is the appropriate way to redefine the section counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Test part one}
\section{Test section}

\part{Test part two}
\section{Test section}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]